# Why do I get a 421 Misdirected Request error with HtmlUnit and not with curl, OKHttp and standard browsers?

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I have a HtmlUnit "script" that has been running for months, but started to fail about a week ago. Some changes were most probably made on the backend of the web site targeted by my script, but I don't have all the details unfortunately.

Basically the script throws an exception on the first attempt to access the main page.  The code looks like this:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage("https://example.com/");
}
```

The exception thrown:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 421 Misdirected Request for https://example.com/
```

I am able to open that same page with curl using this command:

```
curl -L https://example.com
```

Same thing when I try with [OKHttp client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/), it works and causes no error.

Since I could not find a solution with HtmlUnit, I have tried generate the redirected url using HttpClient:

```
private static Optional<String> getRedirectUrl() throws Exception
{
    final HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NEVER)
        .build();

    final HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI(EXAMPLE_SITE)).GET().build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

    return response.headers().firstValue("location");
}
```

But then I get a 403 Forbidden error when I attempt to access this redirected url using HtmlUnit (it works if I open the redirected URL in a standard browser).

I am wondering if there are any limitations with HtmlUnit that I am not aware of?

Comment: Please open an issue for HtmlUnit (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit) and i will try to help.
Is the URL you are using public?

Comment: Great thank you.  The new issue can be found here: https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/518